# Getting Binding Errors but there is no Binding set?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have this control in my WPF window;

```
<TextBlock Name="txtMyTextBlock"
          Text="{x:Static Resources:Strings.SOME_LABEL_IDENTIFIER}"
          Margin="10,10,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Style="{StaticResource WindowTitleStyle}" />
```

and when the window is loaded, I get this error in the Output Window;

> Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property
>   not found on 'object' ''MyViewModelClass' (HashCode=7754709)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem='MyViewModelClass'
>   (HashCode=7754709); target element is 'TextBlock'
>   (Name='txtMyTextBlock'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

As far as I can tell, the 'Text' property on the TextBlock 'txtMyTextBlock' is set to an Embedded Resource string... why am I getting binding errors here?

Answer (score 0):

in your Text="" you are binding to a static resource. this can be done, but your syntax is wrong. what you want is something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <System:String x:Key="FirstName">Jared</System:String>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{StaticResource FirstName}"/>
```

[here is a good walk-though/tutorial](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/04/21/tutorial-creating-a-staticresource-and-binding-to-it/)

Comment: This resource is to a .resx strings file - StaticResource bindings in that case don't work. I think my problem is actually in the style where there are some triggers. I got a bit thrown by the error.

Comment: True. As always though, I notice my mistakes *after* posting my questions... apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should not be in this bit of code, `x:Static` does not cause binding errors, i suspect that there is a failing binding in the style you applied, e.g.

```
<Style x:Key="WinTitleStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ThisFails}" />
</Style>
<!-- ... -->
<TextBlock Name="myTB" Text="{x:Static prop:Resources.WinTitle}"
           Style="{StaticResource WinTitleStyle}"/>
```

Even though the style setter does not have [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) i get an error from that binding:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'ThisFails' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow'
>   (Name='Window')'. BindingExpression:Path=ThisFails;
>   DataItem='MainWindow' (Name='Window'); target element is 'TextBlock'
>   (Name='myTB'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')